# Php fopen fputs text + length characters

Tags: php, xml, fopen

I don't see wat goes wrong but what I do is try to make a new xml file. This is my test code:

```
   $filename = "my_xml_file_".date("Y_m_d_His").".xml";
   $path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../mydirectory/'. $filename;
   $fd = fopen ($path, "w");
   fputs($fd, '<xml><test></test></xml>');
   fclose($fd);
```

My file should contain only:

```
   <xml><test></test></xml>
```

But it contains at the end in my file, the length of the charachters, like:

```
<xml><test></test></xml>24
```

When i do this:

```
   $filename = "my_xml_file_".date("Y_m_d_His").".xml";
   $path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../mydirectory/'. $filename;
   $fd = fopen ($path, "w");
   fputs($fd, '');
   fclose($fd);
```

the file contains only this:
0

What am I overlooking for not getting the length of characters in my xml file? Thanks.

File is correctly saved but changes when I do a download with an ajax call:

```
    $filePath = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../mydirectory/'.$filename;
    $extension = explode('.', $filename);
    $extension = end($extension);

    if (!is_file($filePath)) {
        // file does not exist
        echo "file does not exist: " . $filePath;
        exit();
    }

    $response = new Response();

    // Set headers
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
    if($extension == 'csv'):
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    elseif($extension == 'xml'):
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    else:
          header('Content-type: application/json');
    endif;
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($filePath) . '";');
    $response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($filePath));

    $response->sendHeaders();
    $response->setContent(readfile($filePath));
    return $response;
```

Comment: It looks fine on my localhost. If you're not gonna use `$fd` anywhere else, can you try it with `file_put_contents`? Edit: or try with giving `fputs` a length parameter. (as third argument)

Comment: try changing `$fd = fopen ($path, "w");` to this `$fd = fopen ($filename, "w");`

Comment: The filename is a non existing file, fopen() makes the file if it does not exist.

Comment: @Noman: yes that works, but now the file is saved in my public root, but i want it in a directory just outside the public root in /mydirectory. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

I think the call to this `kernel` guy there is causing some values in the file writing buffer. Please do the following before you write to the file:

```
fflush($file);
```

Example:

```
   $filename = "my_xml_file_".date("Y_m_d_His").".xml";
   $path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../mydirectory/'. $filename;
   $fd = fopen ($path, "w");
   fflush($fd);
   fputs($fd, '<xml><test></test></xml>');
   fclose($fd);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is is not changing anything to my file content, it still has the length of the characters in it.

Comment: The same code works fine for me on PHP 5.5 Can you tell your PHP version?

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.18, you do fflush($fd) ?

Comment: Sorry, yeah it should be `flush($fd)`, not `$file`

Answer (score 0):

What about creating file on root directory and move it in your directory using php [**rename**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function.

Make sure your `$path` is correct.

```
$filename = "my_xml_file_" . date("Y_m_d_His") . ".xml";
$fd = fopen($filename, "w");
fputs($fd, '<xml><test></test></xml>');
if(fclose($fd)) {

    $path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/mydirectory/';
    if(rename($filename,$path.$filename)) {
        echo "move";
    } else {
        echo "not move";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it had to do when i download the file from the server.
On the server the file is saved correctly but not when i download it.

It was because i did:
    $response->setContent(readfile($filePath));

This does not work for xml, I changed it to:

```
 if($extension == 'xml'):
        $doc = new \DOMDocument();
        $doc->load($filePath);
        $response->setContent($doc->saveXML());
    else:
        $response->setContent(readfile($filePath));
    endif;
```